# Vote your own post disabled

Tags: discussion, votes

Trivial thing. Why there's the option to vote your own post if it's not allowed? There's some rationale behind it?

[image]

From a UX point of view it seems to me that the function should be just disabled, instead of letting you click it and then show a message that you can't do it.

Answer (score 7):

This was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) a decade ago on Meta SE: [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12599/270345). It might be worth it to try flagging for it to be reviewed (following [What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/270345)).